# StackApplet crashes when loading stats. What do I do?

Tags: 11.10, configuration, stackapplet

I upgraded to 11.10 (from 11.04), and now StackApplet crashes when loading my stats. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to occur because of a difference in the configuration files between StackApplet in 11.04 and 11.10. To fix it, remove `~/.stackapplet` and log out, then log back in. StackApplet should load as usual, and you just need to add your sites again.

Comment: This is indeed strange because StackApplet is *supposed* to automatically migrate all settings. Oh well, if the fix is this easy, then it's not too big a concern.